# Read Jpeg2000 metadata

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, jpeg2000

I want to find an open source library with BSD/MIT (or equivalent) licence that is able to read XML (or any) metadata from `.jp2` files. Research so far:

- [OpenJpeg](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg) doesn't reading metadata
- [EasyExif](https://github.com/mayanklahiri/easyexif) doesn't
  support the jpeg2000 format
- [Grok](https://github.com/GrokImageCompression/grok) is using the AGPL licence which I can't use.
- [Kakadu](http://kakadusoftware.com) is commercial

Any ideas?